# Amazon s3 Services for J2me in blackberry

Tags: web-services, blackberry, java-me, amazon-s3

I am developing a social network app for blackberry. In it i need to upload audio and image files and retrieve it at later time. So for that i need to use Amazon services. I downloaded the j2me toolkit for Amazon s3 from below link.

I have keys from amazon services. I can create buckets through it and i can store,retrieve and delete String objects. But there is no option in jar to store images or any other files.

So anyone please help me out to store image and audio  files.   Thanks in advance.